# Code for date_range didnot work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I didnot get the expected result for date_range function.
I got the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_index'"

please help.

I created a Dataframe, 
called the date_range function and put it into a variable
used the variable from previous function to set the column as index to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Open':[12,15,20,23,25,30,23,22,21,21,22,20,12,13],
    'Close':[8,9,9,12,12,23,12,12,12,8,4,2,8,5]
    })

rng=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/14/2018',freq='D')
rng

df.set_index(rng,inplace=True)
df
```

Expected results: The date column should be created as an index.

Actual Result : Error with message "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_index'"

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the above code.

Comment: In your actual code did you do something like `df = df.set_index(rng,inplace=True)` and then later try to do `df.set_index(rng,inplace=True)`?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Is that the problem? If so, what's the reason for the issue?

Comment: I started another session and re-wrote the whole code and this time, I wrote the set_index function directly i.e. df.set_index(rng,inplace=True)  and this worked.  Please let me know what is the reason for the previous error?